# Tinkoff Kassa API python

Tags: python, requests

хотел бы создать интеграцию с Tinkoff Kassa API, но не сильно получается - выдает 400 ошибку. Хотел бы понять, в чем проблема

Ссылка на документацию - https://www.tinkoff.ru/kassa/develop/api/payments/init-description/

Код, который я пытался использовать:

```
import requests    
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br', 'host': 'securepay.tinkoff.ru', 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/112.0}', 'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty', 'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors', 'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin', 'Accept-Language': 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3', 'Connection': 'keep-alive'}
api_request = requests.post('https://securepay.tinkoff.ru/v2/Init', headers=headers, data={'TerminalKey': 'TerminalKey(убрал, но он есть)', 'Amount': 100, 'OrderId': 0})
```

Comment: OrderId (Идентификатор заказа в системе продавца) должен быть string(36), судя по документации.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В ваших параметрах не хватает поля "token".
Подбронее про процедуру получения токена => [*тык*](https://www.tinkoff.ru/kassa/dev/payments/#section/Podpis-zaprosa)

Для Python я реализовал следующий алгоритм получения токена:

```html
r = {
    "TerminalKey": terminalkey,
    "Amount": 1000,
    "OrderId": "1",
    "Password": password
}

t = []

for key, value in r.items():
    t.append({key: value})
t = sorted(t, key=lambda x: list(x.keys())[0])
t = "".join(str(value) for item in t for value in item.values())
sha256 = hashlib.sha256()
sha256.update(t.encode('utf-8'))
t = sha256.hexdigest()
r["Token"] = t
```